# How to fix "Error: The view for SrcController::view() was not found." in CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Good day!

I am a new learner of using CakePHP framework. I just finished installing CakePHP and was trying to build a project using PhpStorm.

However, after running the application, I've got an Error Message on screen with regards to the `SrcController`. I did follow the steps given on screen but after following them, I got this Error again...

```
Error: The view for SrcController::view() was not found.
```

I actually did some improvements now. But there's still an error... Here's my BooksController code:

```
<?php
/**
* @property BooksController $BooksController
*/
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Controller\AppController;
class BooksController extends AppController {
    public function display()
    {
        $name = 'Book';
        function index() {
            $this->Book->recursive = 1;
            $books = $this->Book->find('all');
            $this->set('books', $books);
        }
        $this -> render('index');
    }
}
?>
```

And here's my index:

```
    <table>
    <thead>
    <th>ISBN</th><th>Title</th><th>Author</th>
    </thead>
<?php foreach($books as $book): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $book['Book']['isbn'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book['Book']['title'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book['Author']['name'] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

And the error are:

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: books [APP/Template\books\index.ctp, line 6]
Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/Template\books\index.ctp, line 6]
```

Comment: Like how am I going to do that? I've got a lot of sample codes here yet it's all useless, they got errors..

Comment: I have created the function view at the SrcController. However, I have it empty. I guess it's one of the root problem, what should I put there?

Comment: Thanks! Some part have been shown. But, I've got this error in the index which says...

Comment: Notice (8): Undefined variable: books [APP/Template\books\index.ctp, line 6]

Comment: Okay, heres the logic. I have 2 database tables named books and authors. It's actually a One-to-Many Relationship.

Comment: Here's my BooksController Code...    <?php
/**
 * @property BooksController $BooksController
 */
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Controller\AppController;
class BooksController extends AppController {
    public function display()
    {
        $name = 'Book';
        function index() {
            $this->Book->recursive = 1;
            $books = $this->Book->find('all');
            $this->set('books', $books);
        }
        $this -> render('index');
    }

}
?>

Comment: I can't do chatting for now. I'm new here, I only have 6 reputations.

Comment: I'll put my codes below as an answer, kindly look for it. Please...

Answer (score 0):

Just try it

```
<?php
/**
* @property BooksController $BooksController
*/
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Controller\AppController;
class BooksController extends AppController {
    public function display()
    {
        $name = 'Book';
        function index() {
            $this->Book->recursive = 1;
            $books = $this->Book->find('all');
            $this->set(compact('books));
        }
        $this -> render('index');
    }
}
?>
```